# Is it possible to color raws in excel from pattern in shell?

Tags: excel, linux, shell

I would like to color excel file raws that match a specific pattern.

I have seen that it's possible to do it using Perl with

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
```

Are there other possibilities to do that directly in the shell and not using perl?

Thank you!

Comment: You can probably do it with Python instead of Perl if that helps?

Comment: yes, sounds like the best option